# trying to center a div inside a fixed-width div

Tags: css

I have a parent div whose width is fixed at 150px. When I create a child div, firebug says its width is 150px too. Why is this?

Thus, when I try to use margin auto to horizontal align the div, it doesn't make a difference. Is there any way to override the 150px width that is automatically set for the child div?

Comment: Are you assigning the child div a width anywhere?

Comment: Put the html and css you have used

Answer (score 3):

A div by default is a block element and block elements take up the full width of their containing element unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

Because div is a block level element, the default width of the full parent. The width of an inline element content itself adaptive, for example: span element

Answer (score 0):

@j08691 is right about div's being block elements.  You'll either need stylesheet or inline styles that have the following effect:

```
<div style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
  <div style="width: [smaller width]; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;"></div>
</div>
```

..the reason is that the inner div's margin can't automatically determine their size unless the inner div has a width.

[...the text-align stuff is just left over sludge from back in the IE6 (and 7?) days ;-) ]